# Evaluating the relationship between two attributes in a gene study

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a data set for thousands of genes. Each gene has two attributes represented as a percentage range(0-100). One attribute (V3) has a normal distribution but the other (V2) is highly negatively skewed (e.g 99% of the values are greater than 99%). I want to know if the out liars of V2 have any relationship with the V3 attribute? I thought about partitioning the data into percentiles and treat it as categorical which would allow me to use chi-squared test but I am not sure if this is the best method or not. I also would like to get your input as to if a numerical method can be used with this data?

[image: scatter plot of the two attributes]

I am very new at asking questions here so please let me know if there is anything I can do to improve the question.

Thank you

Comment: What does a scatterplot of the data look like?

Comment: Perhaps using an option like `pch="."` in the call to `plot` in $R$ will make the density of points easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try fitting a (linear) model that predicts V3 with the help of the outliers of V2 (or vice versa). Plotting this model and calculating the error (e.g. R^2) will give you an idea of how realistic the model is, i.e. if the attributes are correlated. You can do this in R by using the `glm` function for example.